# How to deal with multiple types of data in one column in R?

Tags: r, database

I have several columns with various types of data in them. For instance, I have some double values like 1.4, 5.6, etc..and I have values below limit detection like < 0.01, < 0.0004, etc. In the Import text Data the columns are detected as character because of that. How can I deal with this?

With the solution of this I expect to do stats with all the values, taking into account the below limit detection values.

Comment: We can remove the `<` symbol after reading the column and convert it to `numeric`.  try `library(dplyr); library(hablar);df1 %>% mutate_if(is.character, list(~ str_remove(., "[<]")) %>% retype`

Comment: What do you mean by taking into account the below limit detection values? If you are running stats it seems like they values need to be numeric. As for what you set the value to for < 0.01 there should be some kind of standard in your field. You could presumably count is as 0 or 0.00999 but that is not a coding issue and is beyond the scope of this site

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `tidyverse`, Remove the `<` and then `retype` the columns

```
library(tidyverse)
library(hablar)
dfN <- df1 %>%
         mutate_if(is.character, list(~ str_remove(., "<")) %>% 
        retype
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you want to handle your data.

1. If you want to want to work with numeric values you have to first determine what to do with values like `<0.01`. Do you simply want to treat is as `0.01`? If yes you can use `sub` to delete the `<` symbol: `as.numeric(sub("<", "", mycol))`
2. If you want to work with categorical variables you can bin them together, i.e. define groups `<0.01`, `<0.1`  `<1` etc. In R you can do so using the case_when function:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the numbers you could use `gsub("[^0-9.]+","",YourList)` This version should keep the decimals. 
I tested with various formats before posting, but you might wanna have a look at your results before going further in your code.

```
> test <- c(1:4,"+65","<5","6>","46-6",6.5,"azer95.5")
> gsub("[^0-9.]+","",test)
[1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "4"    "65"   "5"    "6"    "466"  "6.5"  "95.5"
```